# Return different value for GraphQL enum in GraphQL-java

Tags: java, graphql, graphql-java

I am having following enum in the application.

```
public enum State {
    Started("newly started"),
    Hold("hold on"),
    Running("still running"),
    Stop("just stopped");

    private String value;

    State(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

I have GraphQL schema as well for the same. I am using GraphQL-java library not GraphQL-spqr or GraphQL-java-tools. When I am returning this enum, it's name is being returned but I want to return it's assigned value i.e. "still running" for Running enum, "just stopped" for Stop enum etc. Is there any way in GraphQL-java?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> it's name is being returned but I want to return it's assigned value

This is by design. From the [spec](http://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Enums):

> Enums are not references for a numeric value, but are unique values in their own right. They may serialize as a string: the name of the represented value.

Enum values are serialized as their names. You may be able to provide an additional value that can be used internally during execution, but this value will not be used in the response.

Comment: and that's what I am exactly looking for. so, you are there is no such way I can achieve that? Can I use some directive or any other way to do that? An example would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to do here, but if you need `running` instead of `Running` as the name, then just use `running` as the name.

Comment: I just updated my question. I want to return the value ("newly started", "hold on"..) to the client because I've space-separated strings which I can not keep as it is in Enum.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not possible. You would have to use underscores instead of spaces in the name and convert them client-side.

Comment: The GraphQL spec has no bearing on java enums, or the way they're serialized. You can represent your GraphQL enums with whatever values you'd like in your schema, and it's up to you to provide mapping between GraphQL and java, e.g. via `graphql.schema.idl.EnumValuesProvider`. That said, GraphQL won't allow you to use spaces in enum value names.

Answer (score 0):

You can map your GraphQL enums to Java enums however you'd like by providing custom mapping.
But GraphQL won't allow your enum values to have spaces. So you can either have enums without spaces, or you can declare your state fields as a String.

Or you could provide those strings as descriptions of enum values.

```
GraphQLEnumType.newEnum()
    .name("State")
    .value("Started", State.Started, "newly started")
    // ...
    .build();
```

Or via SDL:

```
enum State {
    "newly started"
    Started
}
```

Those descriptions can be queried with:

```
query {
  __type(name: "State") {
    enumValues {
      name
      description
    }
  }
}
```